# Flutter Android build fails on intermediates/compiled_local_resources/debug/out' is not a readable directory

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

My Android build fails when building a `debug` app to the device. The error is:

```
[ +201 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
[        ] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
[   +1 ms]    > Path
'/Users/***/Documents/dev/***/***/dev/***/build/firebase_dynamic_links/intermediates/compiled_local_resources/debug/out' is not a readable
directory.
```

I've edited the path above to hide the project details but the path to `build/firebase_dynamic_links/intermediates/compiled_local_resources/debug/out` is indeed not there. This happened after I had created an app release bundle and the path to `release/out` exists.

I have tried `flutter clean` but it still throws the error. I guess I need to clean the gradle cache but am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced the same problem with flutter apple_pay package
I solved this issue by running

```
rm -rf android/.gradle
```

then I did

```
cd android 
gradlew clean
```